# Check to see if one to many results exist in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How can I go about checking to see if a one to many table contains one or more results in a temporary table?

```
@colors Temp Table
------
Red
Blue
Green
Pink
Yellow


SELECT 
    u.userID,
    u.color
FROM 
    USERS as u
WHERE 
    u.field = '123'
AND
    (
        (SELECT t2.userColor FROM TABLE2 as t2 WHERE t1.userID = u.userID) IN (SELECT color FROM @colors)
    )
```

In this case, TABLE2 contains one or more results such as "RED" and "GREEN" for users. I need to be able to see if either of those exist in the temp table.

In short, `(SELECT t2.userColor FROM TABLE2 as t2 WHERE t1.userID = u.userID)` could contain one or more records for the user and I need to see if any of those colors exist in the temp table.

Comment: This makes no sense. Can you post some actual details? Like the table ddl and sample data? I have no idea why somebody decided to give this an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is with `exists` as I don't get the impression you needed to return any of the info about the matched color.

```
SELECT u.userID, u.color
FROM USERS as u
WHERE u.field = '123'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT t.userColor
    FROM TABLE2 AS t INNER JOIN @colors AS c ON c.color = t.userColor
    WHERE t.userID = u.userID
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use cross/outer apply:

```
SELECT 
    u.userID,
    u.color,
    [tmpColors].[count]
FROM 
    USERS as u
outer apply
(select count(1) as [count] from Table2 t join @colors c on c.color = t.userColor where t.userId = u.userId) as [tmpColors]
WHERE 
    u.field = '123'
```